# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyDictionary'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this small English Dictionary using Python3, the app is running and functioning perfectly when run in Pycharm, but when I run it in Command Line in Windows, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python Projects\Windows\Dictionary\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyDictionary'
```

What is the reason for this? is there any way to fix it?

I find Python modules really confusing sometimes, I keep installing packages and modules, but then suddenly they disappear and lose functionality, is it because they get out of date or any other reason for these Python issues? If yes, can I auto-update all the modules whenever a specific app is being run?

Further, I am kind of new to Github and all ,now I published my code in the Github repository, if anybody wanted to use it, they can't because after converting the python file to an executable it gives me that error, so whoever wants to use my app will get the same error...

Github Repository: https://github.com/totenkopf7/Screen-Notifier.git

Python Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary

root = Tk()
root.geometry("450x550")
root.title("Dictionary")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.config(bg="black")


def space():
    space = Label(text="", bg="black")
    space.grid()


def find_meaning():
    word = entry.get()
    dictionary = PyDictionary(word)
    definition = dictionary.getMeanings()
    label_list = []

    try:

        if "Noun" in definition[word]:
            label_list.append("Noun: " + definition[word]["Noun"][0])
        if "Verb" in definition[word]:
            label_list.append("Verb: " + definition[word]["Verb"][0])
        if "Adjective" in definition[word]:
            label_list.append("Adjective: " + definition[word]["Adjective"][0])
        if "Adverb" in definition[word]:
            label_list.append("Adverb: " + definition[word]["Adverb"][0])
            # After each word form definition has been added,
            # join them together with two new lines in between each definition
        label = "\n\n".join(label_list)

    except Exception:
        label = "Wrong word entered!"


    return label


def write():
    label.config(text=find_meaning())
    entry.delete(0, END)

def funcs(z):
    find_meaning()
    write()

space()
dic_text = Label(root, text="Dictionary", fg="#3dcc8e", bg="black", font=("arial", 15, "bold"))
dic_text.grid()

space()
entry = Entry(root, font=("times", 23, "bold"))
entry.grid()

space()

btn = Button(root, text="Explain", bg="#3dcc8e", fg="black", font=("bold"), command=lambda: [find_meaning(), write()])
btn.grid()

space()
label = Label(root, text="Translation", background="#3e3e3e",
              width=40, height=21, relief=FLAT, state=DISABLED, disabledforeground="#3dcc8e", wraplength=200,
              justify=LEFT)
label.grid()

root.bind('<Return>', funcs)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: They do not dissapear. It seems that you're installing dependencies on another python interpeter. Not one that you use for running scripts.

Comment: @sashaaero, well, probably, but that's another issue I face all the time, I close an app in Pycharm and open it in like a week or two, it says no interpreter found, I have to change its interpreter

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be a comment, but i can't do that yet so I will write here.

I think this is probably a problem of you using Venvs. Pycharm makes virtual enviroments for you so that you can install dependences for different projects separately, without globally installing them.

Try installing the packages directly from the command line instead of doing it from the Pycharm terminal if you want to have them for your entire PC and don't want to mess with virtual enviroments.

Hope it helps.